# random bitmaps covert number to resource ID

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am trying to Display 2 random dice rolls at the same time. I know i need to convert a die number to a resource ID but How? This is the code that I have so far...

What would a good way of coding this?

```
    void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

    // randomize random number generator using current time
   srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) ); 

    // pick random die values
    int die1 = 1 + rand() % 6; // first die roll
    int die2 = 1 + rand() % 6; // second die roll


    pPCAvatar = (CStatic *) GetDlgItem(PC_AVATAR);
    pIDCPicture = (CStatic *) GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE2);

    //image for the avatar
    CString Image1;
    CString Image2;
    CString Image3;
    CString Image4;
    CString Image5;
    CString Image6;

    //initialize entity from the constructor
    Image1 = "pcture1.bmp";  // die face # 1
    Image2 = "pcture2.bmp";  // die face # 2
    Image3 = "pcture3.bmp";  // die face # 3
    Image4 = "pcture4.bmp";  // die face # 4
    Image5 = "pcture5.bmp";  // die face # 5
    Image6 = "pcture6.bmp";  // die face # 6




    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a `switch/case` statement.

```
CString dieImage;

switch(dieValue)
{
case 0:
    dieImage = "filename1";
    break;

case 1:
    dieImage = "filename2";
    break;

// Rest of case statements

}
```

Another way is to use an array.

```
const CString dieImages[6] =
{
    "filename1",
    "filename2",
    "filename3",
    "filename4",
    "filename5",
    "filename6"
};

const CString& dieImage = dieImages[dieValue];
```

If you want to work with more than one value you can put it into a function and make the array a static member variable

```
const CString& GetDieImage(int dieValue) const
{
    return dieImages[dieValue];
}
```

the just call it like so

```
const CString& dieImage1 = GetDieImage(dieValue1);
const CString& dieImage2 = GetDieImage(dieValue2);
```

To use an array to manage the image name you might change your code to something like below.

```
void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    static const CString dieImages[6] =
    {
        "filename1",
        "filename2",
        "filename3",
        "filename4",
        "filename5",
        "filename6"
    };

    // pick random die values
    const int die1 = 1 + rand() % 6; // first die roll
    const int die2 = 1 + rand() % 6; // second die roll

    const CString die1image = dieImages[die1];
    const CString die2image = dieImages[die2];


    // ... rest of your code goes here ...
}
```

Comment: _I_ don't have multiple personalities but **I** do. _I_ and **I** would be more than happy to update our answer if you can point to what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: We updated the our answer with a code snippet using source from your question. Hopefully this will get you on your way.

Comment: Just a quick note. Get familiar with [const-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/overview-const.html). it's a good thing!

Comment: filename is either the name bitmap file or the ID of the resource (if you are using strings for resource ID). Otherwise change `CString` to `UINT` and change the strings to the resource ID. To load the image call `CBitmap::LoadBitmap`.  This a different problem, you need to research how to load and use resources in MFC and Windows. If you continue to have problems post another question with your new problem and reference your question.